# Get the most common element of an array using Pyspark

Tags: arrays, pyspark, find-occurrences

How can I get the most common element of an array after concatenating two columns using Pyspark

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [['a','a','b'],['a']],
  [['c','d','d'],['']],
  [['e'],['e','f']],
  [[''],['']]
]).toDF("arr_1","arr2")

df_new = df.withColumn('arr',F.concat(F.col('arr_1'),F.col('arr_2'))
```

expected output:

```
+------------------------+
| arr  | arr_1   | arr_2 |
+------------------------+
| [a]  | [a,a,b] | [a]   |
| [d]  | [c,d,d] | []    |
| [e]  | [e]     | [e,f] |
| []   | []      | []    | 
+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
df1 = df.select('arr_1','arr_2',monotonically_increasing_id().alias('id'),concat('arr_1','arr_2').alias('arr'))
   
df1.select('id',explode('arr')).\
   groupBy('id','col').count().\
   select('id','col','count',rank().over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(desc('count'))).alias('rank')).\
   filter(col('rank')==1).\
   join(df1,'id').\
   select(col('col').alias('arr'), 'arr_1', 'arr_2').show()

+---+---------+------+
|arr|    arr_1| arr_2|
+---+---------+------+
|  a|[a, a, b]|   [a]|
|   |       []|    []|
|  e|      [e]|[e, f]|
|  d|[c, d, d]|    []|
+---+---------+------+
```

Comment: My original DataFrame contains more columns. How can get all columns including the new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can **`explode the arr`ay** then by doing **`group by count, Window`** we can get the most occurring element.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [['a','a','b'],['a']],
  [['c','d','d'],['']],
  [['e'],['e','f']],
  [[''],['']]
]).toDF("arr_1","arr_2")

df_new = df.withColumn('arr_concat',concat(col('arr_1'),col('arr_2')))

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
df1=df_new.withColumn("mid",monotonically_increasing_id())
df2=df1.selectExpr("explode(arr_concat) as arr","mid").groupBy("mid","arr").agg(count(lit("1")).alias("cnt"))
w=Window.partitionBy("mid").orderBy(desc("cnt"))
df3=df2.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") ==1).drop(*["rn","cnt"])
df3.join(df1,['mid'],'inner').drop(*['mid','arr_concat']).withColumn("arr",array(col("arr"))).show()

#+---+---------+------+
#|arr|    arr_1| arr_2|
#+---+---------+------+
#|[d]|[c, d, d]|    []|
#|[e]|      [e]|[e, f]|
#|[a]|[a, a, b]|   [a]|
#| []|       []|    []|
#+---+---------+------+
```